# Radiation pressure applied to different color surfaces

Tags: photons, radiation-pressure

Does the value of radiation pressure exerted by photons from sunlight vary when applied to surfaces of a different color? 
More specifically, ranging from pitch black to white surfaces.

Also, is there a special case of this when applied to mirrors?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. For example a (perfectly) black surface would absorb all photons, and hence the radiation pressure would be given by:
$P_R=\frac{E_f}{c}$
Where $E_f$ is the photon energy flux and $c$ is the speed of light.

A (perfect) mirror *reflects* all the light, and so you would get double the momentum transfer, and hence double the radiation pressure.

Different coloured objects reflect only some of the light, and so you would need to know which frequency they reflect and absorb - this is the *spectral reflectance curve*. Using this would let you calculate the radiation pressure, which would fall somewhere between a perfectly black and perfectly mirrored object. You would also need to know the spectral energy distribution of the object in this case.

Let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: I did! Thank you for bringing it to this point because I do have a few more curiosities: 

  1. How do you define the "photon energy flux" ?

2. How should the formula for radiation pressure be interpreted? (If you would be so kind to give a more literal explanation)

3. Why does a (perfect) mirror receive double the momentum?

Comment: 1. Amount of photon energy per square meter per second. 2. The radiation pressure tells you the amount of force per square meter of the objects cross section that faces the radiation. 3. For a black object the photon is simply absorbed, but for a mirror it collides into the object (transferring some momentum) and then "bounces" back (transferring the same amount of momentum again).

Comment: I meant what exactly does c have to do with determining the amount of pressure applied?

Comment: The momentum of a photon is E/c, where E is the energy. The pressure is rate of change of momentum per area, and so is given by (E/c)/t/A or just E_f/c where E_f=E/(tA) is the energy flux of photons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A totally reflective surface will bounce the photon back, resulting in twice the momentum change in merely absorbing it.

However, it gets a little more complex because an absorbing surface heats up and then itself radiates. If there is perfect thermal transfer it will radiate isotropically. So shape, and materials, matter with absorbers.

Comment: How does the photon get absorbed if the surface is totally reflective? I understand why it would heat up ( due to the amount of kinetic energy transfered to the surface in question when it comes in contact with the photons, right?

Comment: Surfaces differ in reflectivity. For 100% reflective no photons are absorbed. When the reflectivity is 0% they all get absorbed and the photon energy appears as heat in the target